# pandas dataframe loop through rows

Tags: python

I have a 6000*5 `dataframe` which is like:

```
 0      1      2     3     4
 0.001  0.020  0.502 0.773  0.332
 0.021  0.120  0.202 0.113  0.000
 0.001  0.420  0.432 0.003  0.123 ...
```

Now I want to loop through each of those 6000 rows and compare values in the same row to get the largest element and store column index in a new dataframe. Say, for the first row the largest element should be 0.773, second row should be 0.202, third row be 0.432. So I need a new `dataframe` like

```
3 2 2
...
```

How to approach this question?

Comment: am i to infer that you have no prior experience with Python?  maybe no prior experience with computer programming in general?

Comment: I am new to python, if this were in java it could be quite easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use idxmax() like below.

```
df['max_col'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

> **DataFrame.idxmax(axis=0, skipna=True)**
>
> Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.
> NA/null values are excluded.
>
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html